# VSCode typescript importing json file highlighting issue

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have some strange behaviour when importing json files using the import statement in typescript while using VSCode. Note this is not an issue with typescript itself just VSCode highlighting.

I have edited my tsconfig.json adding resolveJsonModule and esModuleInterop with the value of true to my compiler options to enable importing json within typescript.

Also I have added this package to my project
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-d-ts
and added a typeRoots attribute to the tsconfig.json with a value of ["node_modules/json-d-ts"]

I've imported the json file (found at src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json) within a module (found at src/firebaseApp.ts) which is within a parent directory, thus the import looks like this:

```
import databaseUrl from "./config/firebaseDatabaseURL.json";
```

VSCode does not complain about this import:

[image: Good import highlighting]

However I have another module which imports the same file at a different level in the project directory, this module is found at test/utils.ts its import look like this:

```
import serviceKey from "../src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json";
```

This time VSCode does not seem to like the relative import and highlights the module as missing:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix configure VSCode to fix this problem?

Here is the relevant section of the result of running tsc --traceResolution:

```
======== Resolving module '../src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json' from '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/test/utils.ts'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json.ts' does not exist.
File '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json.tsx' does not exist.
File '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json.d.ts' does not exist.
Directory '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json', target file type 'JavaScript'.
File '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json.js' does not exist.
File '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json.jsx' does not exist.
Directory '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json', target file type 'Json'.
File '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name '../src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json' was successfully resolved to '/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json'. ========
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [
            "node_modules/*",
            "src/types/*"
        ]
    }
},
"include": [
    "src/**/*"
],
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/json-d-ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: First, make sure that `test/utils.ts` is included based on the `files`, `include`, and `exclude` settings in `tsconfig.json`, because VS Code doesn't apply the compiler options specified in `tsconfig.json` to excluded files.  If that isn't the problem, run `tsc` with the `--traceResolution` option to get more information about what happens when it tries to resolve the `../src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json` module.

Comment: The problem might happen because you're trying to import a JSON file outside of your TypeScript project directory

Comment: Hi thanks Matt, I've added my tsconfig.json and the result of tsc for the relevant section, I don't think its a typescript issue as it does resolve the module and the code work. But vscode does not seem to be as smart resolving the module.

Comment: In fact if test/* is put in the "include" within the tsconfig.json then building fails with: "error TS2497: Module '"/home/jty/April2018/vs-server/src/config/firebaseServiceKey"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct." otherwise if its not included then it compiles fine. VSCode complains either way.

Answer (score 7):

I have faced similar issue, check your file is included as @Matt McCutchen said, the file which contains
`import serviceKey from "../src/config/firebaseServiceKey.json";`
should be included under `src` folder as you described in the `tsconfig.json`

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*"
],
```

---

In my case, it was a test file which should **not** be included in the build. Because of that I have decided to ignore that highlight in the vs.

```
// @ts-ignore
import packageJson from '../../../../package.json';
```